# Cómo cargar uno por uno todos los archivos de audio que comienzan con "chunk_" dentro de un directorio específico sin usar la biblioteca os?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, archivo, count

```py
from pathlib import Path

def process_audio_files(file_name):

    #Edit the file
    transcription = file_name + "edited"
    
    return transcription
    

audio_chunks_path = "audio_chunks/"
names_structure = "chunk_"

#initializes the counter variable assuming that within the directory there may not be any files beginning with that word
n = 0
transcription = ""

if(audio_file.startswith(names_structure)):
    n += 1

#once all the files have been accounted for
for i in n:
   file_name = audio_chunks_path + names_structure + str(i) + ".mp3"
   
   transcription = process_audio_files(file_name)
   print(transcription)

   Path(file_name).unlink() #delete this chunk audio file
```

#Dentro del directorio `audio_chunks` hay una n-ésima cantidad de archivos cuyo nombre comienza con `chunk_`, lo que necesito es poder iterarlos y modificarlos con el`audio_chunk_processing_function(n)` function one by one in this order.

```
audio_chunks/chunk_0.mp3
audio_chunks/chunk_1.mp3
audio_chunks/chunk_2.mp3
audio_chunks/chunk_3.mp3
audio_chunks/chunk_4.mp3
audio_chunks/chunk_5.mp3
audio_chunks/chunk_6.mp3
audio_chunks/chunk_7.mp3
audio_chunks/chunk_8.mp3
...
audio_chunks/chunk_n.mp3
```

¿Cómo hacer este bucle? (considerando que solo se deben contabilizarse aquellos archivos que comienzan su nombre de esta manera, eso se pueda determinar con expresiones regulares)

Ahí está el problema, no se cuantos archivos hay en ese directorio, además solo se deben contar los archivos cuyo nombre comience con `chunk_`. Tengo problemas para poder combinar el contador con una expresión regular de validación para poder determinar cuántos de ellos hay en el directorio y luego hacer el ciclo `for`.

En este caso NO necesito extraer los nombres de los archivos porque ellos ya los se, lo que necesito saber es cuantos de ellos hay, que empiecen con ese nombre "chunk_"

Comment: O sea que la pregunta se reduce a "¿Cómo obtener una lista ordenadas de archivos según un cierto patrón?".

Comment: @CandidMoe Sí, la idea es detectar todos los archivos que comiencen con la palabra "chunk_" dentro del directorio "audio_chunks", luego ir pasando "chunk_0.mp3", luego "chunk_1.mp3", luego "chunk_2.mp3", luego "chunk_3.mp3", ...

Comment: El problema es que la pregunta tambien necesita de la regex, para funcionar porque dentro del directorio hay otros archivos por eso no se si esta realmnete duplicada

Comment: @CandidMoe Ademas estaba revisando la otra pregunta y estan usando la libreria os que aqui no puedo usar, de todos modos aqui solo necesito contar la cantidad de ellos n-1 que empiezen con ese nombre y no extraer los archivos

Comment: Te sirve path.glob("chunk_*.mp3")? donde path es un objeto que representa a un Path del modulo pathlib. Esto devuelve un iterador que va obteniendo los archivos que empiezen con chunk_ y tengan extensión mp3. A vos no te va  a importar los archivos, por lo que podés ignorarlos y simplemente iterar sobre eso e ir sumando 1 a una variable (o usar comprensión de generador junto a la función builtin sum)

Comment: @DanteS. Si me serviria cualquier cosa que me permita contabilizarlos, y a la vez asegurarme que sean archivos que comiencen con ese nombre "chunk_"{i}, luego le voy pasando los valores incrementales de la variable n a la funcion

Comment: ¿Probaste la solución de Dante? ¿era lo que estabas buscando?

Comment: intente colocar algo asi Path("audio_chunks").glob("chunk_*.mp3") , pero no me da una cantidad de archivos sino que me imprime que es un generator object

Comment: @multiple Ahora he editado la pregunta para simplificarle, quizas sea mas simple pensarla asi pero no estoy seguro almenos con el nuevo codigo creo que puedo evitar usar las regex, pero aun asi tengo que conseguir el valor de n

Comment: Exacto, tenes que dar algo de tu parte para obtener el numero. Como te habia dicho en mi comentario, deberas usar un bucle for sobre el generador e ir sumando uno a la variable.

Comment: Ahi lo consegui, muchas gracias por la ayuda